# How transcription factor influence gene expression?

Tags: gene, cancer

I am studying about gene regularity network(GRN). I'm interested to work on cancer detection to find start reasons of this particular illness.

I'm trying to find out how the transcription factor(TF) influence genes expression increase or decrease in a biochemical network. cancer that I try to study and analyze is Liver which is popular in recent years in Iran. the main area of research is developing an influence maximization model for finding pathways in biochemical networks. I am seeking to find out the patterns of TF which can act a key role to initiate cancer illness. 
What would happen that a normal gene held in the mutation process?

my source is a thesis of MA program major in IT-Bioinformatic

Comment: Could you expand more your question with what kind of data do you have, and what have you tried to find a solution? Like which papers propose a solution or a method and why they didn't solve your issue, or which programs/methods are you thinking to use. Also it might help to know which kind of cancer are you studying or in which types of cancer will you analyze

Comment: @llrs thanks for your notes. cancer that I try to study and analyze is Liver which is popular in recent years in Iran. the main area of research is developing an influence maximization model for finding 
pathways in biochemical networks

Comment: Ok, could you [edit] the question to include this information? Also don't forget to mention which papers and research have you looked at